# Cache SQL Update for daily reuse

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a big table with 40 million rows in a Table. I am having to update the entire table because I don't want anything to missed. The Update Command Is being used to get the value from a different table and using this to join on.

```
Update D
Set D.Key = S.Key
from Activity D with (NOLOCK)
inner Join Account S
on D.ID = S.ID 
OPTION (HASH JOIN)
```

With Activity D being the Big Table 40 million and Account Table S being a 1.2 Million, that's why I have take the HASH Option Join.

Anyways I am having to do this update everyday in an Execute SQL task in my ETL Process,Just wondering since not much gets changed and no index exist to speed in the process up in the table. Is there a way to speed this process up at all, whether there is a way to cache this so everynight its not having to do the whole thing from scratch or would wrapping this in a Stored Proc speed things up rather than just using a SQL Script as I am doing at the moment?

Thank you

Comment: The obvious approach is to put an index on `Account(ID, Key)`.

Comment: Is there a way to do the opposite and have a index on the activity table to get a massive performance boost instead. I didnt mention but I am having to do the above script for 20 other Tables, Account table just being one of them against the Activity table.

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach to avoid that UPDATE could be to use a trigger on `dbo.Activity` table thus:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgIU_Activity_UpdateKey
ON dbo.Activity
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

IF UPDATE(ID)
BEGIN
    UPDATE d
    SET D.Key = S.Key
    FROM dbo.Activity d INNER JOIN dbo.Account s ON d.ID = s.ID
    WHERE d.ID IN (SELECT i.ID FROM inserted i)
END

END
```

After every INSERT / UPDATE on Activity table, if there are any changes within `dbo.Activity.ID` column then it will update the `Key` column.